# Importing node modules in a WordPress plugin

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, wordpress

I'm using `wp_register_script` and `wp_enqueue_script` to bring in some custom JavaScript logic for the admin screen of a WordPress plugin I'm developing.

The problem comes when I try to add `import` statements at the top of my JavaScript in order to bring in a couple node modules. Understandably, this gives me the following browser console message:

> import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

What is the standard way to tell WordPress to treat a custom bit of JavaScript as a module? And are there other steps I need to follow in order to make sure that my node modules can be imported?

Comment: Are you expecting WordPress to process the JS and understand the import in any way? I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to actually accomplish. All that the script and style loaders do is register URLs/files to be spit out in script/link tags in the header/footer, along with some simple name-based dependency management. Or do you just want type=module to be spit out on a script tag?

Comment: I would say that having type=module spit out in my script tag would be a necessary prerequisite for loading other node modules, yes? Assuming so, that's the main thing i'm looking to fix. From there, I can stash my node modules in any old public place (or create a script that does it) and have things work.

Comment: Okay, I think you are looking for [what the OP did here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/366114). Read through the comments because they solved a bug there, too. Basically, you are going to have to hijack the printing function and include the `type=module` on your own. Also, WordPress has a [key/value store on their dependency class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/WP_Dependencies/add_data/) that you can bind per handle that might make it easier to identify when printing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What is the standard way to tell WordPress to treat a custom bit of JavaScript as a module?

All you need is `type="module"` on the `<script>` tag and the browser will treat this script as ECMAScript module.

With wordpress, to add the `type` attribute on a script, first enqueue the script

```
function enqueue_plugin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('module_handle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/path/to/module.js')
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_plugin_scripts' );
```

Then Add `type="module"` to `module_handle` using `script_loader_tag` hook

```
function set_scripts_type_attribute( $tag, $handle, $src ) {
    if ( 'module_handle' === $handle ) {
        $tag = '<script type="module" src="'. $src .'"></script>';
    }
    return $tag;
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'set_scripts_type_attribute', 10, 3 );
```

> And are there other steps I need to follow in order to make sure that my node modules can be imported?

You can't use bare import, for example : `import $ from "jquery"` will fail in the browser.
To import from the `node_modules`, you must provide the full path to the module otherwise the browser
will complain with `Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"`

Here is some examples:

This won't work

```
import $ from "jquery";
import Swiper from "swiper";
```

This will work

```
import "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js" //because jquery doesn't have browser-compatible ES module
import Swiper from "./node_modules/swiper/js/swiper.esm.browser.bundle.js";
import Swiper from 'https://unpkg.com/swiper/js/swiper.esm.browser.bundle.min.js'; //from external source
console.log($, Swiper) //will output jquery and swiper
```

Here is a good article on [ECMAScript modules in browsers](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/)

Comment: in what file do I need to put the `enqueue_plugin_scripts` function and `set_scripts_type_attribute` function?

Comment: @alramdein you can put it in `function.php` file of your theme or in any plugin file

Comment: what if the file you specify imports another file which does not have an extension

Answer (score 0):

You could try to load it from unpkg

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/package_name@version"></script>
```

Hope this helps.